# Error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am getting error of duplicate entries. I have a dataframe *df*. I am converting it into another dataframe by following code. However, I am getting error when I unstacking and then reindexing the dataframe as *df1* in the loop.

**How I can avoid duplicate entries problem?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [{'Petal_width': 0.2, 'Petal_length': 1.4, 'Sepal_width': 3.5, 'Sepal_length': 5.1, 'Colour': 'a', 'Species_name': ' Setosa'}, {'Petal_width': 0.3, 'Petal_length': 1.4, 'Sepal_width': 3.0, 'Sepal_length': 4.6, 'Colour': 'b', 'Species_name': ' Setosa'}, {'Petal_width': 0.2, 'Petal_length': 1.3, 'Sepal_width': 3.6, 'Sepal_length': 4.7, 'Colour': 'a', 'Species_name': ' Setosa'}, {'Petal_width': 0.2, 'Petal_length': 1.5, 'Sepal_width': 3.1, 'Sepal_length': 4.6, 'Colour': 'c', 'Species_name': ' Setosa'}, {'Petal_width': 0.2, 'Petal_length': 1.4, 'Sepal_width': 3.6, 'Sepal_length': 5.0, 'Colour': 'b', 'Species_name': ' Setosa'}, {'Petal_width': 0.4, 'Petal_length': 1.7, 'Sepal_width': 3.9, 'Sepal_length': 5.4, 'Colour': 'b', 'Species_name': ' Setosa'}, {'Petal_width': 0.3, 'Petal_length': 1.4, 'Sepal_width': 3.4, 'Sepal_length': 4.6, 'Colour': 'b', 'Species_name': ' Setosa'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']) #numerical
print(df)

values = [[0.1, 0.2, 1.3, 1.8, 2.5], [1.0, 1.4, 4.5, 5.1, 6.9], [2.0, 3.0, 3.4, 4.4], [4.3, 5.0, 5.5, 6.3, 7.9]]


for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    s=pd.cut(df.iloc[:,i],values[i]).dropna()
    x=s.map(lambda x : x.left).astype(int).to_frame('V')
    y=s.map(lambda x : x.right).astype(int).to_frame('V')
    y['r']=abs((x.V-df.iloc[:,i])/(y.V-x.V))
    x['r']=abs(1-y['r'])

    df1=pd.concat([x,y]).set_index('V',append=True).\
           r.unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index(drop=True).\
            reindex(columns=values[i],index=df.index,fill_value=0)
    print(df1)
```

Comment: Seems to work fine with the sample data.

Comment: Could you include what your end-goal, or expected output should be? Finding it difficult to solve without that. 

However, something like `reset_index` after concatenating may work.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. It does not work with new dataset. I trying to do something like this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169924/pandas-int-or-float-column-to-percentage-distribution/57170224#57170224) . However it give duplicate error.